# How to access to the items in Applications folder

Tags: c#, windows-8

In Windows 8 Developer Preview there was an "Applications" folder, with all the metro and desktop applications. I discovered that this folder stil exist in Windows 8 Consumer Preview.
How I can read all elements in this folder with C#??

The folder is:

```
%­windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}
```

Comment: What is the task that you are trying to accomplish?  Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a tutorial to access to Application Folder in Win8 in this URL:

http://justinangel.net/ReverseEngineerWin8Apps

Comment: Yes, but I have to access to this shell folder because reading all apps may be too complex...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}")` but it don't work with this folder :(

Comment: The folder is: "C:\Program Files\Applications" but you need to follow the tutorial first to grant access privileges for your user to this folder.